# Custom model in Groovy templates

Tags: templates, groovy

Is it possible to have a custom, map-like class (although not related to map) in a Groovy template, in a way that I can specify how properties from my custom class are mapped to model properties? E.g. if we have property `$firstName` I would like to customize how `firstName` is obtained from my custom class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `MarkupTemplateEngine`, yes, it is possible. See http://groovy-lang.org/templating.html#markuptemplate-basetemplate